# Where should I place the code for async fetch/axios data for the <List>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized, react-window

I checked all the sandboxes for `react-window` (`react-virtualized-auto-sizer`, `react-window-infinite-loader`)

They both use mock data

Where should I place the code for async fetch/axios data for the `<List>`?

sandboxes:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bvaughn-react-window-fixed-size-list-vertical-forked-wmmc3x
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-dhawan-fwlruv

Comment: Does the data need to be pulled from API only once (say, at page-load) - or will it need to be refreshed based on a condition? Have you considered `useEffect` as a possible option?

Comment: will pulled once on first page load, and each row will have a button to "delete" button that can be clicked and removed, which will make it re-fetch the data again